# and return at the end of a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sometimes I spot the code like this:

```
def bar
  #......
  if response && response.body
    #......
    render(:text => html) and return
  end
end
```

I wonder, is there any point of using `and return` at the very end of a method?

Comment: In this case - no, not at all.

Comment: Yup.. Not in this case, except if someone adds more code and conditions :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw such code only not at the bottom of a method (it makes sense because render is not the end of the method). But here I don't see any point.

See [Avoiding Double Render Errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 5):

This is to help avoiding `double render errors`. [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: at the very end of a method!

Answer (score 0):

This ensures that you return after the `render` because if you call `render` multiple times, you get an exception: `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action`

One of the reasons is if someone edits your code to become as below, you'd be in trouble:

```
def bar
  ...
  x = true
  ...
  if x
   render(:text => html)
  end

  ...
  render(:text => html)
end
```

Comment: at the very end of a method!

Comment: If you see my comment above, I understand it's at the very end of the method. This is to prevent FUTURE code edits where things get added AFTER your line, making it NOT the last line of the method.

Comment: Good point. In other words, it is not necessary for the computer to run the code, but it is useful for maintenance by human.

Comment: Whatever @sawa says, print it and post it on your wall :-)

Comment: Nevertheless, it is not idiomatic ruby to have useless returns in a method.